# Konsole -- 'Unable to locate package power' -- Power Manager unable to initialize

Tags: kubuntu, power-management, konsole

My power manager was working, but now it's not. It won't start up, I cant purge it in Konsole or install it again, because Konsole won't find it.

Comment: Which version of Kubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If I run

```
apt list --installed | grep -i power
```

in Kubuntu 18.04, I see:

```
libpowerdevilcore2/bionic-updates,now 4:5.12.7-0ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
libpowerdevilui5/bionic-updates,now 4:5.12.7-0ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
libupower-glib3/bionic-updates,now 0.99.7-2ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
powerdevil/bionic-updates,now 4:5.12.7-0ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
powerdevil-data/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,now 4:5.12.7-0ubuntu0.1 all [installed]
powermgmt-base/bionic,bionic,now 1.33 all [installed]
ruby-power-assert/bionic,bionic,now 0.3.0-1 all [installed]
upower/bionic-updates,now 0.99.7-2ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64 [installed]
```

I suggest you try

```
sudo apt install --reinstall powerdevil
```

If that doesn't work, try

```
sudo apt install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop
```